# How to unit test waterline model create method instance

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sails.js, sinon

I want to unit test a function in my sails.js application using Mocha(test framework) and Sinon(test double library). This is how the function under test looks like

```
function saveNotifications(notificationData, cb){
  checkForDuplicates(notificationData, (err, isDuplicate) => {
    if(isDuplicate) return updateNotification(notificationData, (err, updatedData)=> { cb(err, updatedData) })
    // No duplicate exists, so save the notification in db
    Notification.create(notification).exec((err, savedData) => {
      return cb(err, savedData)
    })
  })
})
```

Although I was able to fake `checkForDuplicates` and add some tests for that. But when I wanted to stub(or fake) `Notification.create(notification).exec` method in order to check if create method was called once for particular test case, I was not able to figure out how to do that. Neither do I understand how to stub chained methods nor am I able to stub simple `Notification.create` object itself. I am assuming some gaps in my understanding of how to stub waterline method instances. Appreciate any help/advice.

---

**What I have tried**

I tried to do simpler things first i.e. stubbing create method

```
it('#saveNotifications({userId: "1", message: "Test message"}, cb)', (done) => {
 sinon.stub(Notification, 'create');
 saveNotifications({userId: "1", message: "Test message"}, (err, result) => {
   try {
     expect(err).to.not.throw;
     expect(err).to.be.null;
     expect(result).to.be.not.null;
     sinon.assert.calledOnce(Notification.create);
     sinon.restore();
     done();
   } catch(e){
     sinon.restore();
     done(e);
   }
 })
```

but this gives error

```
TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent property create
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues you mentioned, let's sort them out one by one

> 1. Stub simple Notification.create object?

You have already written the right code for this but you are not referencing the correct model object. Instead of `Notification` object, use `sails.models.notification` i.e.

```
sinon.stub(sails.models.notification, 'create')
```

---

> 2. How to stub chained methods

Fake the returned value and use stub in the returned function i.e.

```
sinon.stub(sails.models.notification, 'create').callsFake(function(){
  return {
    exec: theStubbedChainFunction
  }
})
var theStubbedChainFunction = sinon.stub().yields(null, { id: '1', message: 'canned response'})
// Then you can assert to test 
sinon.assert.calledOnce(theStubbedChainFunction)
```

If you had more chained function (e.g. `Notification.update(criteria).set(valuedToUpdate).fetch().exec(function(err, updatedRecords){...})`, you could follow the same principal e.g.

```
sinon.stub(sails.models.notification, 'update').callsFake(function(){
  return {
    set: sinon.stub().callsFake(function(){
            return {
                      fetch: sinon.stub().callsFake(function(){
                         exec: theStubbedChainFunction
                      })
                   }
         })
  }
})
```